# Plotting hits within given areas of circle - Code for setup getting bloated

Tags: objective-c, class, optimization, syntax, nsmutablearray

**[Alternative approach given by user1118321, old and new code listed for reference]**

I am busy writing a small app which allows a game of darts 501 to be scored. I have set up a class to contain the individual scoring areas (GDSBoardArea) and one mutable array which represents the entire dart board and holds all the individual scoring class instances.

I have written the code for one section (20 score, inner and outer, and triple and double 20) but the issue I have is that the code for this is quite bloated and was woindering if there was a better way to init all the areas with less, more managable code as I will have to repeat this below another 19 times for the other sections?

I have a class that holds the settings for the various individual areas, one class to hold all these areas and helper functions.

I did attempt to try reuse the CGPoints and area arrays but this simply caused issues I think related to the fact that it updates a reference as the scoringAreas addObject does not copy the array object (Please correct me if I am wrong).

I setup the scoring areas once when the application runs using the **createAreas** function and I cant seem to reuse the CGPoints and arrays holding them.

**My questions are**:

1 - Is there a way to pass in a variable array of CGPoints to "GDSBoardArea"'s last parameter instead of having to create the CGPoints, add them to an array and pass the array in.

2 - Does the mutable array method addobject copy or reference the object passed to it? Is it there any way to update an array and then make a copy of it to a "master" mutable array so that the master array is effectively holding a different array in each element. I am basically try to avoid having to create a new array for each of the master arrays elements.

**createAreas**

```
-(void)createAreas
{
scoringAreas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

/*
    20 scoring section
*/

// 20 score - Inner triangle area
/////////////////////////////////////////

// Set up CGPoints for area
CGPoint pt_inner20_1 = CGPointMake(368.0f, 234.0f);
CGPoint pt_inner20_2 = CGPointMake(413.0f, 234.0f);
CGPoint pt_inner20_3 = CGPointMake(389.0f, 360.0f);

// Add points to array for passing to GDSBoardArea Class
NSMutableArray * areaPointsArray_Inner20 = [NSMutableArray array];
[areaPointsArray_Inner20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_inner20_1]];
[areaPointsArray_Inner20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_inner20_2]];
[areaPointsArray_Inner20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_inner20_3]];

// Create GDSBoardArea Instance with init values
GDSBoardArea *scoreAreaFor_Inner20 = [[GDSBoardArea alloc] initWithName:@"20-Inner" abbrev:@"20" areaValue:20 pointsArray:NULL];

// Add Array of CGPoints to GDSScoreArea
[scoreAreaFor_Inner20 setPointsForPath:areaPointsArray_Inner20];

// Add ScoreArea to ScoreAreas Class
[scoringAreas addObject:scoreAreaFor_Inner20];

// 20 score - Outer Quadrilateral
/////////////////////////////////////////
CGPoint pt_outer20_1 = CGPointMake(353.0f, 125.0f);
CGPoint pt_outer20_2 = CGPointMake(429.0f, 127.0f);
CGPoint pt_outer20_3 = CGPointMake(415.0f, 208.0f);
CGPoint pt_outer20_4 = CGPointMake(365.0f, 209.0f);

NSMutableArray * areaPointsArray_Outer20 = [NSMutableArray array];
[areaPointsArray_Outer20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_outer20_1]];
[areaPointsArray_Outer20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_outer20_2]];
[areaPointsArray_Outer20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_outer20_3]];
[areaPointsArray_Outer20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_outer20_4]];

GDSBoardArea *scoreAreaFor_Outer20 = [[GDSBoardArea alloc] initWithName:@"20-Outer" abbrev:@"20" areaValue:20 pointsArray:NULL];
[scoreAreaFor_Outer20 setPointsForPath:areaPointsArray_Outer20];
[scoringAreas addObject:scoreAreaFor_Outer20];

// Double 20 Quadrilateral
/////////////////////////////////////////

CGPoint pt_d20_1 = CGPointMake(351.0f, 102.0f);
CGPoint pt_d20_2 = CGPointMake(353.0f, 118.0f);
CGPoint pt_d20_3 = CGPointMake(430.0f, 119.0f);
CGPoint pt_d20_4 = CGPointMake(433.0f, 104.0f);

NSMutableArray * areaPointsArray_Double20 = [NSMutableArray array];
[areaPointsArray_Double20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_d20_1]];
[areaPointsArray_Double20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_d20_2]];
[areaPointsArray_Double20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_d20_3]];
[areaPointsArray_Double20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_d20_4]];

GDSBoardArea *scoreAreaFor_double20 = [[GDSBoardArea alloc] initWithName:@"20-Double" abbrev:@"d20" areaValue:40 pointsArray:NULL];
[scoreAreaFor_double20 setPointsForPath:areaPointsArray_Double20];
[scoringAreas addObject:scoreAreaFor_double20];

// Triple 20 Quadrilateral
/////////////////////////////////////////

CGPoint pt_t20_1 = CGPointMake(367.0f, 214.0f);
CGPoint pt_t20_2 = CGPointMake(368.0f, 226.0f);
CGPoint pt_t20_3 = CGPointMake(412.0f, 226.0f);
CGPoint pt_t20_4 = CGPointMake(413.0f, 214.0f);

NSMutableArray * areaPointsArray_Triple20 = [NSMutableArray array];
[areaPointsArray_Triple20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_t20_1]];
[areaPointsArray_Triple20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_t20_2]];
[areaPointsArray_Triple20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_t20_3]];
[areaPointsArray_Triple20 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt_t20_4]];

GDSBoardArea *scoreAreaFor_triple20 = [[GDSBoardArea alloc] initWithName:@"20-Triple" abbrev:@"t20" areaValue:60 pointsArray:NULL];
[scoreAreaFor_triple20 setPointsForPath:areaPointsArray_Triple20];
[scoringAreas addObject:scoreAreaFor_triple20];

}
```

**ScoringAreas** is a Mutable Array that simplt represents all the areas of the board and is defined as:

```
@property (strong, atomic) NSMutableArray  *scoringAreas;
```

**GDSBoardArea Class** in case its relevant

```
// GDSBoardArea.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GDSBoardArea : NSObject
@property NSMutableArray *pointsForPath;
@property int areaValue;
@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *abbrev;

-(id) init;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name_ abbrev:(NSString *)abbrev_ areaValue:(int)areaValue_ pointsArray:(NSMutableArray*)pointsArray;
@end
```

--

```
// GDSBoardArea.m

#import "GDSBoardArea.h"

@implementation GDSBoardArea

-(id)init{
if (self = [super init]) {
    /* perform your post-initialization logic here */
    [self setName:@""];
    [self setAbbrev:@""];
    [self setAreaValue:0];
    [self setPointsForPath:NULL];
}

return self;
}

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name_ abbrev:(NSString *)abbrev_ areaValue:(int)areaValue_ pointsArray:(NSMutableArray*)pointsArray
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.name = name_;
    self.abbrev = abbrev_;
    self.areaValue = areaValue_;
    self.pointsForPath = pointsArray;
}
return self;
}

@end
```

**Code change as per answer from user1118321**:

*createAreas function was completely removed and direct calculation done as follows (Will add more as it is fleshed out until complete)*

```
-(GDSBoardArea *)checkPointsScore:(CGPoint)tappedPoint
{
#define NUM_PIE_SLICES 20
#define NUM_RINGS 7
#define DEG_PER_SLICE 18
#define PII 3.141592653
#define OFFSETFORBOARD 99.3f

float radius_board = 344.0f;

float thickness_innerbull = 16.0f;
float thickness_outerbull = 18.0f;
float thickness_innerSingleScore = 116.0f;
float thickness_double = 16.0f;
float thickness_outerSingleScore = 80.0f;
float thickness_triple = 20.0f;
float thickness_noscore = 78.0f;

GDSBoardArea *tappedScoreArea = NULL;

double dartX = tappedPoint.x;
double dartY = tappedPoint.y;

double centerX = 390.0f;
double centerY = 390.0f;

double angle = atan2((dartY - centerY), (dartX - centerX)) * 180 / PII;
angle = angle + OFFSETFORBOARD; // To force slice 0 to correspond to Score of 20
int slice = (int)floor(angle / DEG_PER_SLICE);

NSLog(@"angle: %f", angle);
NSLog(@"slice #: %i", slice);

return tappedScoreArea;
}
```

Comment: For reference, `createAreas` isn't an `init` method, nor is it called by an `init` method.  I'm not sure what your question is exactly, but there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your `initWithName` method.  Your `init` method is wrong though.

Comment: Ugh apologies, didnt mean the init function, will edit question accordingly.

Comment: btw: don't use `self` in your init methods. It is not guaranteed to be setup completely. And you might wanna use `instancetype` instead of `id` as your I it's return types. Regarding your questions: it's not entirely clear to me what you actually want to accomplish :( I have to admit I'm on mobile right now but I'll take a look at it later!

Comment: Thanks HAS, my question was actually unrelated to the init method as nhgrif pointed out and I adjusted my question and title accordingly although I will rework the init methods I have using your advice.
The method I was using was probably going to work but amounted to a lot of work and user1118321 provided a math based solution which I am going to use to replace the hard coded method of plotting areas at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were me, I wouldn't bother at all with storing the various areas of the board. First, they aren't triangles and quads, and second, it's fairly easy to calculate them. You can figure out which "pie slice" you're in by getting the arctangent of the point where the dart lands, like this:

```
double angle = atan2((dartY - centerY) / (dartX - centerX));
```

You can then convert that to an integer between 1 and # of slices like this:

```
int slice = (int)floor(angle / anglePerSlice);
```

Next, you can figure out which ring the user is in by using the distance from the board's center:

```
double deltaX = dartX - centerX;
double deltaY = dartY - centerY;
double distFromCenter = sqrt (deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
```

You could then convert that into an index by looking it up in an array. You have a single array containing all the boundaries in a single slice. All slices have their boundaries at the same distances. So it would look something like this:

```
double concentricBounds[kNumBounds] = { 10, 15, 100, 110, 200, 210 }; // Just made up - I don't know what distances you're using.
bool done = false;
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; (i < kNumBounds) && (!done); i++)
{
    if (distFromCenter < concentricBounds [ i ])
    {
        done = true;
        index = i;
    }
}
if (!done)
{
    ...point was off the board...
}
```

So now you have the slice it was in and the ring it's in. You can just have a 2D array of point values to look up into:

```
int points [][] = { {50, 25, 20, 60, 20, 40 }, { 50, 25, 5, 15, 5, 15 }, ...etc... };
```

Note that `atan2()` returns angles with 0° being parallel to the X-axis and it increases in counter-clockwise order. So you may have to rotate the scores to orient your board correctly.

Comment: Thanks user1118321 that works although I adjusted the angle calculation and added an offset to rotate the x axis counterclockwise so that the slice # 0 corresponded to the Number 20 of the dartboard. Have only worked on the slice part for the moment and added to my question for others to reference.